# Can't get JSON data jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, undefined, getjson

The url is correct; when I enter it in my browser I get the JSON data, but the data isn't displaying on my page after calling jQuery's GET request. How come?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <h4 id="test">yo</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
function getNutrition() {
 $.getJSON("https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=banana&max=25&ds=Standard%20Reference&offset=0&api_key=rWKfuG6YjQU9h0WMNksynapfFqcr3BJWK5giCqRQ").then(function(data) {
    // $('h4').html(data.list.item[0]);
    $('#test').html(data);
})}

getNutrition();
```

Comment: What's the value of `data`, when do you call `getNutrition`? Does an element with the `id` test exist and does it exist when you call `getNutrition`? There aren't enough details here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgbve3w1/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I added more code. Yes, the ID test is defined, and I did call getNutrition(). There's no error message returned by console when I run my code. The data just isn't displaying as it should.

Comment: See my fiddle above. Simply instead of `data.list.item[0]` use `data.list.item[0].name` or whatever property name you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display json on your page, you need to parse json in any way before.

The simplest method is to use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
$('#test').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused cause in another code that I wrote I didn't use JSON.stringify but called data like I did above, and I was able to get back the JSON data successfully. I thought $.getJSON automatically handles the parsing? Is there something different about this particular case that it requires using JSON.stringify?

Comment: JSON — JavaScript **Object** Notation. It is very similar to casual object or array. To access its content you need parse it. For example with `JSON.parse()` to convert it into object. And when you can print it using cycle. `$.getJSON` is short version of `$.ajax({ url: url, dataType: 'json', data: data, success: callback });`

Comment: You need to wrap it with ``<pre>`` or ``<textarea>`` to keep the ``JSON.stringify(data)`` format.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing anything since `item[0]` is an JSON *Object*. Try getting the right property out of it like `item[0].name` or `item[0].group`
If you want to *print* the JSON part you're interested in - use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
function getNutrition() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=banana&max=25&ds=Standard%20Reference&offset=0&api_key=rWKfuG6YjQU9h0WMNksynapfFqcr3BJWK5giCqRQ").then(function(data) {
    // console.dir(data);
    $('h4').html(data.list.item[0].name);
    $('#test').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  })
}

getNutrition();
```

```html
<h4></h4>
<pre id="test"></pre>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do I have to use JSON.stringify whenever I want to make a JSON get request? It needs to convert the data and parse it as a string first, but I thought $.getJSON handles that? Because as part of another code that I wrote, I didn't use JSON.stringify but called data as I did above, and I was able to get back the JSON data successfully.

Comment: Also, for the line of code that I commented out, I was specifically targeting the first object, which does display when I call JSON.stringify on the data as you've suggested